# pythonからsinaweibodyを使って、weiboの投稿を取得したい

Tags: python

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。

プログラムの内容

```
from snspy import APIClient
from snspy import TwitterMixin      # suppose you are using Twitter

APP_KEY = '294703483'            # app key
APP_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624'      # app secret
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize'  # callback url
YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN='2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE'

client = APIClient(TwitterMixin,
               app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
               access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN, expires=EXPIRES_TIME)

print client.statuses.user_timeline.get()
```

プログラム実行
エラー内容

```
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# python suerte.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "suerte.py", line 2, in <module>
from snspy import APIClient
ImportError: No module named snspy
```

pythonからsinaweibodyの情報については[michaelliao](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO)から参照しました。
ACCES TOKENはMichaelLiaoと違い[weibo guide](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/)から取得しました
{"access_token":"2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE","remind_in":"157679999","expires_in":157679999,"uid":"5973036902”}

エラーが何故起きるかわかる方がいれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: タグを編集しました。質問に無関係なタグは書かないで下さい。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ImportError: No module named snspy
> ```

インポートしている`snspy`というモジュールが見つからない、という事です。

`python snspy`で[検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=python%20snspy&oq=python%20snspy&aqs=chrome..69i57.595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20snspy&nfpr=1)すると、[sinaweibopy](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy) 内のモジュールであることがわかります。

なので、sinaweibopyをインストールすればいいです。
と言いたいところですが、[setup.py](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/blob/master/setup.py) を見ると、インストールするモジュールとしてsnspyが書かれていません。

```
py_modules = ['weibo'],
```

この為、pip等でsinaweibopyをインストールしてもsnspyは含まれません。

snspyを使用したい場合はファイルを直接ダウンロードする必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 1):

[snspy.py](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/blob/master/snspy.py)はこちらのファイルですが、このファイルにTwitterMixinの定義はないと思います。

Comment: snspy.pyのファイルで間違えないです。TwitterMixiの定義がないので必要ないと思います。しかしhttps://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopyではTwitterMixinを使っているのがよく分かりません。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージの通り、snspyというモジュールを見つかりませんでした。
snspy.pyのファイルはsuerte.pyと同じディレクトリになる必要があります。